# How to select from one column or the other?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table with friends and their friendship status (0-rejected, 1-accepted)

```
userA   userB  status
-------------------
john    chris   1
chris   bob     1
mike    chris   1
```

How do I select all of chris' friends to get an output like this?

```
john
bob
mike
```

Comment: You might say it's redundant, but I would treat the table as a one-directional relationship of A->B. Thus, if there's a chris->bob, then chris is friends with bob; but you require a bob->chris for bob to be friends with chris. Think of like how it works on some game consoles. Outside of that, you'll have to join the table to itself.

Comment: In case of rejections, how do you treat the following: john->chris (0) and chris->john (1)? Does this mean that one user accepted/requested friendship with the other, who then rejected? I don't want to stray too far from your original question, but how about a separate column that simply contains user id's (delimited) of all the friends with established "friendships" (bidirectional "accept"). That would decrease the number of rows necessary for deducing friendships between users. Again, maybe there is a purpose to store "rejections"?

Comment: a delimited column is almost never the way to go (it's non-normalized) and here it would present the same problems as before. What if delimited column A has an id B, but delimited column B doesn't have an id A? Same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression for this, something like:

```
select 
case when userA = 'chris' then userB when userB = 'chris' then userA end as friend_name
from  your_table
where 
(userA = 'chris' or userB = 'chris') and status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  full outer joins

```
SELECT column-name-list FROM table-name1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table-name2 
ON table-name1.column-name = table-name2.column-name;
```